# Using sed with gnuplot to plot specific lines from a file in a loop

Tags: bash, sed, gnuplot

I want to plot pictures with a loop in a gnuplot script but there is a problem with the line of "sed". Does anyone know how to solve it?

Here is my script:

```
do for [i=1:2] {
   str_n=sprintf('%d',i)
   set term png
   set output str_n.'.png'
   plot "<(sed -n '(1+45*(i-1)),(45+45*(i-1))p file.dat'" u 2:5 w l
   set output
}
```

Comment: `sed` syntax is incorrect...Please show the content of `file.dat`

Comment: file.dat is a file with 450 rows and 5 colomns, and i wanna plot a picture with every data block of 45 rows and 5 colomns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the gnuplot loop variable `i` inside the sed command. In order to do that, I'd make use of `sprintf` when constructing the sed command:

```
cmd = sprintf("<sed -n '%d,%dp' file.dat", 1+45*(i-1), 45*i)
plot cmd u 2:5 w l
```

This allows you to calculate the numbers using gnuplot before constructing the command for sed.

Better yet, you should use gnuplot's built-in capability to plot a specific range of lines:

```
plot "file.dat" every ::(1+45*(i-1))::(45*i)
```

Comment: ty for ur help, Tom. Ur methods work so well, u totally got me, ty very much,xd

Answer (score 0):

try something like this inside your string

```
sed -n '$(( (1+45*(${i}-1)) )),$(( (45+45*(${i}-1)) )) p' file.dat"
```

also the `<(` is a bit strange because i dont know if this part of the string or a try of redirection but i guess at least a `)` is missing at the end in case of string pattern.

Comment: i do not know if i made any mistake with ur method... but it do not work so well.